# select data based on the next rows and ids

Tags: sql, oracle

```
I have the following table and data,
 TABLE - DEAL
ID  DEALID
1   DEAL1
2   DEAL2
ALL DEAL2
3   DEAL2
4   DEAL5
5   DEAL5
ALL DEAL6
```

I want to get only the data as below

```
ID  DEALID
1   DEAL1
4   DEAL5
5   DEAL5
ALL DEAL6
```

I want to select data based on the value of id column and dealid column.
If the value of id is 'ALL' and corresponding dealid repeats, omit all records with that dealid

Comment: Question is unclear. Please provide what you have done so far.

Comment: i tried using distinct, but not getting the correct data

Comment: When there is All in id column, get deal id and the particular deal should be omitted if it repeat with another id. If not repeat. Keep it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on sample data you posted, see if this helps. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, dealid) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select '1'  , 'deal1' from dual union all
  5     select '2'  , 'deal2' from dual union all
  6     select 'ALL', 'deal2' from dual union all
  7     select '3'  , 'deal2' from dual union all
  8     select '4'  , 'deal5' from dual union all
  9     select '5'  , 'deal5' from dual union all
 10     select 'ALL', 'deal6' from dual
 11    ),
 12  all2 as
 13    -- DEALIDs that contain different ID values, and MAX of them is ALL
 14    (select dealid
 15     from test
 16     group by dealid
 17     having min(id) <> max(id)
 18        and max(id) = 'ALL'
 19    )
 20  select t.id, t.dealid
 21  from test t join all2 a on a.dealid <> t.dealid;

ID  DEALI
--- -----
1   deal1
4   deal5
5   deal5
ALL deal6

SQL>
```

Comment: if suppose there is a 3rd column which i use for where condition to select data, i can add the condition in all2 before group by, can i do that?

Comment: Try and see what happens.

Comment: Yes it worked Littlefoot. Not sure why am I not able to post any question. Any help.

Comment: I don't know why you can't post questions. Is there any info on the screen? If not, go to SO Meta (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and ask for help there.

Comment: Yes, I have this message on screen, when I click 'Ask Question'. You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Comment: Try to read this (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), maybe you'll find something useful. If not, as I said - ask for help on Meta.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it. May be I can edit this question and check